# set tags=tags in gvimrc not working, unless set it explicitly

Tags: vim, ctags

I have a problem to set my tags file correctly. It use to work without problem after I reinstalled the system. error message like

```
E433: No tags file
E426: tag not found: Pids
```

accurs when I press `ctrl+]`.

I have this line in my .gvimrc file

```
set tags=~/projectdirectory/tags
```

and tags-exuberant installed properly.

**It works fine when I type `:set tags=~/projectdirectory/tags` in gvim**

I also tried use `set tags=~/projectdirectory/tags;/`

All other .gvimrc settings function well. How this could be possible?

UPDATE:

**I have solved the problem, it is because I have multiple tags setting in ~/.gvimrc, vim take the last one in current session.**

Comment: `~/.gvimrc` is only useful for GUI-specific settings. Use `~/.vimrc` for generic settings. Also, why do you call your `tags` file "ctags"?

Comment: @romainl I am using gvim, even I keep the tags setting in ~/.vimrc. It still not working. The problem is I cannot set tags path in either ~/.vimrc or ~/.gvimrc. I can only literally type the command every time I start vim. Do you know how can I check the configuration in ~/.gvimrc or ~/.vimrc are correctly set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the actual effective value (after starting GVIM) via

```
:verbose set tags?
```

The option might have been overwritten by a later `:set` command, or a plugin.

Even if you only use GVIM, it's recommended to put the general settings into `~/.vimrc` (which is also sourced in GVIM), and keep `~/.gvimrc` reserved for GUI-specific settings. An important difference between the two is that the latter is only sourced at the very end, so it's unsuitable for configuring plugins.